# Intel NUC 6I5SYH, Ubuntu 16.10 and Dell UP2715K - Screen goes blank occassionally

Tags: 16.04, intel-nuc

I installed on a new Intel NUC 6I5SYH Ubuntu 16.10 and everything runs smoothly. However, the screen goes black occassionally. I run it via MiniDisplay port at 4K resolution.

It happens usually when I open a new tab in Firefox or Chromium. It also happens when I try to move the window. Everything works fine after a few seconds, however it is annoying.

Does anyone had the same experience? Any solution?

Lukas

Comment: Have you tried with *Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS*. It is debugged and polished, and is new enough for my NUC6i3SYH. (I have no 4K screen, only a 2K screen). - It is easy to try live without installing, booted from USB or SD card.

Comment: I have this same issue except it's with Ubuntu Server 16.04. Intel's website officially says they support Ubuntu Desktop 16.04.1, but says nothing about servers... :(